# APK gives error during upload to appstore for android for Smartface 4.5

Tags: smartface.io

When you try to upload Google play ther result of publish APK it gives below error with Smartface 4.5. How to solve?

[image]

Comment: Hi @Alex Can you help me with the codereader control in smartface. It's working well in app but one problem that it doesn't autofocus we have to do it manually trough default camera app then it does in Smartface Developed App. Please help me through.